# Private permission for some users

Tags: nodes, users, organic-groups

I use drupal 7 for creating a site for patient remote treatment. I have used profile2 and i create to profile types patient and doctors. finally i installed OG groups(treatment). I want to add patients and doctors to this group. Every patients should be assigned by administrator to a doctor. Patient could ask his/her question from his/her doctor and only doctor and patient could see this documents. Is it possible to have private permission for some users?

Comment: If you want only private questions then you can also use private message module

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/612664 this discussion might help you.

Comment: sure..good luck :-)